# bcp database migration

Tags: sql-server, migration, bcp

I want one server to migrate the database to another server. On another server database already exists, then ist all the tables, but they are empty and I want to fill. For the filling, I want to use bcp - database migration. In command line, I wrote the following:

```
bcp [dbo].[aspnet_Profile] in "c:\SQLAzureMW\BCPData\dbo.aspnet_Profile.dat" -E -n -b 10000 -a 16384 -S servername.database.windows.net -U username@servername -P "password" -d databasename!
```

The name of the user and the server name passvord written correctly.

When I run I get this error:
[image]
error = Packet size change not supported by server, default used.

Then I fixed packet size to the size of a default. I removed the "-a".

```
bcp [dbo].[aspnet_Profile] in "c:\SQLAzureMW\BCPData\dbo.aspnet_Profile.dat" -E -n -b 10000 -S servername.database.windows.net -U username@servername -P "password" -d databasename!
```

Then I got the following error:
[image]

Who can tell what I should do, or is there a good way to move the database?
I also used the SQL Azure Migration Wizard,but it don't help me.

Comment: Was this a better fit back on [SO] being about Azure and all?

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason that did not work, and really was not password correct because I used the password to these characters who divided password to pieces, and of that reason but it was not correct. I used to password ",", "$" and other characters.